# Simple Template-Driven Form Angular4 is giving error

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-ngmodel

Making a simple 'Template-Driven Form' I am getting error though I've not done anything special. This is a simple form with one input with one required validation. That's all. Can someone help me out?

**abc.component.html**

```
<form #customForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="alpha(customForm)">

  <input type="text" name="firstName" ngModel #firstName="ngModel" required><br/>

  <div class="red" *ngIf="customForm.firstName.touched">
    <div *ngIf="customForm.firstName.errors.required">Input field is required!</div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="customForm.invalid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**Error:**

> Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined

**Snapshot:**

[image]

Can someone point out, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: use customForm?.firstName?.touched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already declaring a template and assigning it the value of `ngModel` by doing `#firstName="ngModel"`, the `firstName` template variable will already have the `firstName` `FormControl`. So you can simply apply a check on that like this: `*ngIf="firstName.touched"`

Change your template like so:

```
<form 
  #customForm="ngForm" 
  (ngSubmit)="alpha(customForm)">
  <input 
    type="text" 
    name="firstName" 
    ngModel 
    #firstName="ngModel" 
    required>
  <br/>
  <div 
    class="red" 
    *ngIf="firstName.touched">
    <div 
      *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">
      Input field is required!
    </div>
  </div>
  <button 
    type="submit" 
    [disabled]="customForm.invalid">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Here's a [**Working StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-driven-form-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `customForm` you got the refrence to direcly by `#firstName`

```
  <div class="red" *ngIf="firstName.touched">
    <div *ngIf="firstName.errors.required">
      Input field is required!
    </div>
  </div>
```

but still `firstName.errors.required` will throw an error when the form controll is valid you can use `?.` operator or you need to update `ngIf` expresstion like this

```
<div class="red" *ngIf="firstName.touched && firstName.invalid">
```

or you can use '?.' operator

```
  <div *ngIf="firstName.errors?.required">Input field is required!</div>
```

> When the form Control is valid the errors property will be `null`

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-driven-example)